# Spark: How to transpose and explode columns with nested arrays

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I applied an algorithm from the question below(in NOTE) to transpose and explode nested spark dataframe.

When I define `cols = ['a', 'b']` I get empty dataframe, but when I define `cols = ['a']` I get transformed dataframe for the `a` column. See section Current code below for more details. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm looking for required output 2 (Transpose and Explode ) but even example of required output 1 (Transpose)  will be very useful.

NOTE: This is minimum example to highlight the problem, in reality dataframe schema and arrays length vary as in the example  [Pyspark: How to flatten nested arrays by merging values in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68837951/pyspark-how-to-flatten-nested-arrays-by-merging-values-in-spark)

Input df:

```
+---+------------------+--------+
| id|                 a|       b|
+---+------------------+--------+
|  1|[{1, 1}, {11, 11}]|    null|
|  2|              null|[{2, 2}]|
+---+------------------+--------+


root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val: long (nullable = true
```

Required output 1 (transpose_df):

```
+---+------+-------------------+
| id| cols |       arrays      |
+---+------+-------------------+
|  1|  a   | [{1, 1}, {11, 11}]|
|  2|  b   | [{2, 2}]          |
+---+------+-------------------+
```

Required output 2 (explode_df):

```
+---+----+----+---+
| id|cols|date|val|
+---+----+----+---+
|  1|   a|   1|  1|
|  1|   a|  11| 11|
|  2|   b|   2|  2|
+---+----+----+---+
```

Current code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([
  """{"id":1,"a":[{"date":1,"val":1},{"date":11,"val":11}]}""",
  """{"id":2,"b":[{"date":2,"val":2}]}}"""]))

cols = ['a', 'b']

expressions = [f.expr('TRANSFORM({col}, el -> STRUCT("{col}" AS cols, el.date, el.val))'.format(col=col)) for col in cols ]

transpose_df = df.withColumn('arrays', f.flatten(f.array(*expressions)))
             
explode_df = transpose_df.selectExpr('id', 'inline(arrays)')

explode_df.show()
```

Current Outcome

```
+---+----+----+---+
| id|cols|date|val|
+---+----+----+---+
+---+----+----+---+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[stack](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#stack) might be a better option than `transpose` for the first step.

```python
expr = f"stack({len(cols)}," + \
    ",".join([f"'{c}',{c}" for c in cols]) + \
    ")"
#expr = stack(2,'a',a,'b',b)

transpose_df = df.selectExpr("id", expr) \
    .withColumnRenamed("col0", "cols") \
    .withColumnRenamed("col1", "arrays") \
    .filter("not arrays is null")

explode_df = transpose_df.selectExpr('id', 'cols', 'inline(arrays)')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's works well for arrays with static fieds (`date`, `val`).  I made one more question in case the arrays in columns has dynamic field which change randomly . Any help will be appreciated.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69423246/spark-how-to-transpose-and-explode-columns-with-dynamic-nested-arrays