# Spark: How to transpose and explode columns with dynamic nested arrays

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I applied an algorithm from the question [Spark: How to transpose and explode columns with nested arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69418239/spark-how-to-transpose-and-explode-columns-with-nested-arrays) to transpose and explode nested spark dataframe with dynamic arrays.

I have added to the dataframe `"""{"id":3,"c":[{"date":3,"val":3, "val_dynamic":3}]}}"""` , with new column `c`, where array has new `val_dynamic` field which can appear on random basis.

I'm looking for required output 2 (Transpose and Explode ) but even example of required output 1 (Transpose)  will be very useful.

Input df:

```
+------------------+--------+-----------+---+
|                 a|       b|          c| id|
+------------------+--------+-----------+---+
|[{1, 1}, {11, 11}]|    null|       null|  1|
|              null|[{2, 2}]|       null|  2|
|              null|    null|[{3, 3, 3}]|  3|   !!! NOTE: Added `val_dynamic`
+------------------+--------+-----------+---+


root
 |-- a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val: long (nullable = true)
 |-- c: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val_dynamic: long (nullable = true)  !!! NOTE: Added `val_dynamic`
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
```

Required output 1 (transpose_df):

```
+---+------+-------------------+
| id| cols |       arrays      |
+---+------+-------------------+
|  1|  a   | [{1, 1}, {11, 11}]|
|  2|  b   | [{2, 2}]          |
|  3|  c   | [{3, 3, 3}]       | !!! NOTE: Added `val_dynamic`
+---+------+-------------------+
```

Required output 2 (explode_df):

```
+---+----+----+---+-----------+
| id|cols|date|val|val_dynamic|
+---+----+----+---+-----------+
|  1|   a|   1|  1|   null    |
|  1|   a|  11| 11|   null    |
|  2|   b|   2|  2|   null    |
|  3|   c|   3|  3|      3    |  !!! NOTE: Added `val_dynamic`
+---+----+----+---+-----------+
```

Current code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([
  """{"id":1,"a":[{"date":1,"val":1},{"date":11,"val":11}]}""",
  """{"id":2,"b":[{"date":2,"val":2}]}}""",
  """{"id":3,"c":[{"date":3,"val":3, "val_dynamic":3}]}}"""
    ]))

df.show()

cols = [ 'a', 'b', 'c']

#expr = stack(2,'a',a,'b',b,'c',c )
expr = f"stack({len(cols)}," + \
    ",".join([f"'{c}',{c}" for c in cols]) + \
    ")"


transpose_df = df.selectExpr("id", expr) \
    .withColumnRenamed("col0", "cols") \
    .withColumnRenamed("col1", "arrays") \
    .filter("not arrays is null")

transpose_df.show()

explode_df = transpose_df.selectExpr('id', 'cols', 'inline(arrays)')
explode_df.show()
```

Current outcome

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'stack(3, 'a', `a`, 'b', `b`, 'c', `c`)' due to data type mismatch: Argument 2 (array<struct<date:bigint,val:bigint>>) != Argument 6 (array<struct<date:bigint,val:bigint,val_dynamic:bigint>>); line 1 pos 0;
'Project [id#2304L, unresolvedalias(stack(3, a, a#2301, b, b#2302, c, c#2303), Some(org.apache.spark.sql.Column$$Lambda$2580/0x00000008411d3040@4d9eefd0))]
+- LogicalRDD [a#2301, b#2302, c#2303, id#2304L], false
```

ref : [Transpose column to row with Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864222/transpose-column-to-row-with-spark?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stack` requires that all stacked columns have the same type. The problem here is that the structs inside of the arrays have different members. One approach would be to add the missing members to all structs so that the approach of my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69419416/2129801)  works again.

```python
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']

#create a map containing all struct fields per column
existing_fields = {c:list(map(lambda field: field.name, df.schema.fields[i].dataType.elementType.fields)) 
      for i,c in enumerate(df.columns) if c in cols}

#get a (unique) set of all fields that exist in all columns
all_fields = set(sum(existing_fields.values(),[]))

#create a list of transform expressions to fill up the structs will null fields
transform_exprs = [f"transform({c}, e -> named_struct(" + 
    ",".join([f"'{f}', {('e.'+f) if f in existing_fields[c] else 'cast(null as long)'}" for f in all_fields]) 
    + f")) as {c}" for c in cols]

#create a df where all columns contain arrays with the same struct
full_struct_df = df.selectExpr("id", *transform_exprs)
```

`full_struct_df` has now the schema

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- val: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val_dynamic: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- val: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val_dynamic: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- date: long (nullable = true)
 |-- c: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- val: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- val_dynamic: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- date: long (nullable = true)
```

From here the logic works as before:

```python
stack_expr = f"stack({len(cols)}," + \
    ",".join([f"'{c}',{c}" for c in cols]) + \
    ")"

transpose_df = full_struct_df.selectExpr("id", stack_expr) \
    .withColumnRenamed("col0", "cols") \
    .withColumnRenamed("col1", "arrays") \
    .filter("not arrays is null")

explode_df = transpose_df.selectExpr('id', 'cols', 'inline(arrays)')
```

The first part of this answer requires that

- each column mentioned in `cols` is an array of structs
- all members of all structs are `long`s. The reason for this restriction is the `cast(null as long)` when creating the transform expression.

Comment: That's really smart way how to ill up the structs with null fields. Spark's magic works !